# How to rebuild android source code(AOSP) after changing root path

Tags: android, makefile, build, android-source, rebuild

I'd like to re-use the result of android build. When I copy the AOSP full source to another path, it fails to re-build. what I should do to re-use most of outputs only removing small parts of result ?
Is there any way?

for example)
/home/myaccount/android  (build success)
--> /home/myaccount/clone-android  (after moving, so many errors)

(Android version is over 10 which use blueprint, ninja and extra)

Comment: Whats the error that you get?

Comment: so many errors are popup. I guess errors are not meaningful.

Comment: errors are always meaningful.. They might not point directly to the issue but without any kind of log of whats gone wrong how are we meant to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. from you advice, I check the log in details.
there is some cue. thanks.

Assuming after moving full source to other directory.

1. cd android
2. source build/envsetup.sh && lunch myproduct-userdebug
3. m -j1
4. error occurred (error log has this: Loading previous configuration from
   android/bootable/bootloader/edk2/Conf/BuildEnv.sh)
5. rm bootable/bootloader/edk2/Conf/BuildEnv.sh (autogeneated file which has absolute file path)
6. m -j1
7. check system.img in out directory

you can change the -j option as to your system.
this is checked in Android 11 version.